# How to define a function returning a polymorphic value

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

I expect the function `noToState` below works, which travels among all states to find the one which matches the given state number and return the state.

```
class State a where
  allStates :: [a]

class (State a) => IntState a where
-- starting from zero, consecutive                                                 
  stateNo :: a -> Integer

noToState :: (IntState a) => Integer -> a
noToState n = case lookup n $ zip (map stateNo allStates) allStates of
  Just st -> st
  Nothing -> undefined  -- this should never happen
```

However, it yields an error: `Could not deduce (IntState a0) arising from a use of ‘stateNo’`.

So in the code where did I make the mistakes? How should I fix them? Thanks.

Comment: Just as a remark: what are you trying to do? Maybe you don't really need type-classes (or your own) at all

Comment: @CarstenKönig I'm defining the k-path algorithm to convert DFA into regular expression. So I need a way to access the state with numbers :)

Comment: ok - but I guess you have a concrete representation of your DFA/State so why not just make this function for this representation instead? Well never mind - I hope my answer will help you out (and work)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yup it works, thank you very much :-P

Comment: A tip: Use something like `error "Nothing reached in noToState"` instead of `undefined`. This will make the error much easier to debug if what should never happen somehow happens nevertheless (which of course happens more than you'd think.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to something like this:

```
noToState :: (IntState a) => Integer -> a
noToState n = case lookup n $ zip (map stateNo allSts) allSts of
  Just st -> st
  Nothing -> undefined  -- this should never happen
  where allSts = allStates
```

The problem is that you use `allStates` twice and it could be different things

Comment: Cool, it helps! Actually `(State a)` is redundant here as it is implied by the definition of the class `IntState`, and it could be removed safely :)

Comment: Note that this relies on the monomorphism restriction: if you disable that, `allSts` will get typed with the full polymorphic type of `allStates`, leading again to the previous type error. Personally, I would use `ScopedTypeVariables` instead to evaluate `allStates` at the intended type. This is a matter of personal preference, though.

Comment: @chi true think I should include it into the answer? - I think as the restriction is on by default it is not really needed - when someone disables it he/she should know how to fix it

Comment: @CarstenKönig No, I think it's fine as it is. If you really want to add something, you could expand the last line explaining the differences between the typings involved in the OP code and in yours.